# Inverse Laplace transform: is there a nice formula for the step response of a 2nd order system?

Tags: laplace-transform

For the *impulse* response of a 2nd order system given by

$$ H(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$

I was surprised to see there exists a general formula [found by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+%28w%5E2%29+%2F+%28s%5E2+%2B+2+z+w+s+%2B+w%5E2%29) for its inverse Laplace transform:

$$ h(t) = \frac{\omega_n}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\exp(-t\omega_n\zeta )\sinh\Big(t\omega_n \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\Big)$$

Although this formula is not usually found engineering textbooks, it does seem to cover all cases. For example, in the under-damped case $0 < \zeta < 1$, usual formula can be recovered from the above by the simple facts that $\sqrt{\zeta^2-1} = i \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$ in this case and $\sinh(ix)=i\sin x$ in general, so by cancelling out the imaginary units one obtains the [engineering] textbook result for the under-damped case as:

$$ h_\text{underdamped}(t) = \frac{\omega_n}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\exp(-t\omega_n\zeta )\sin\Big(t\omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\Big)$$

Now what my question is actually about is whether there exist similarly nice, general formula for the *step* response of a 2nd system, which means finding the inverse Laplace transform of $Y(s)=\frac{1}{s}H(s)$, i.e. of

$$ Y(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s(s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2)}$$

Alas the brains of Wolfram Alpha [did not have much insight on this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+%28w%5E2%29+%2F+%28s+*+%28s%5E2+%2B+2+z+w+s+%2B+w%5E2%29%29), resulting in a rather ugly looking solution. It is known however that at least for the under-damped case the step response can be written in a fairly nice form:

$$ y_\text{underdamped}(t) = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\exp(-t\omega_n\zeta )\sin\Big(t\omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2} + \arccos \zeta\Big)$$

So, finally, my question is: is there a nice general form for the inverse Laplace transform of $Y(s)$ given above? By nice I mean something that doesn't look too far from the under-damped case so that it can be derived from the general case solution with little computation, hopefully similar to the way $h(t)$ relates to $h_\text{underdamped}(t)$.

Comment: Note that in the expression for the impulse response you should have $\omega_n$ in the numerator of the constant factor, not $\omega_n^2$.

Comment: @MattL.: Thanks, I've corrected it.

Comment: What about $\zeta=1$ (critically damped)?

Comment: I've updated my answer. There is indeed a general expression covering both the underdamped and the overdamped case, and in the limit even the critically damped case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting that the step response is just the integral of the impulse response

$$a(t)=\int_0^th(\tau)d\tau\tag{1}$$

you can enter the impulse response you found in Wolfram Alpha and obtain the [result](http://wolfr.am/8BEEYkgC)

$$a(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n t}}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\left[\zeta\sinh\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right)+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\cosh\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right)\right]\tag{2}$$

or, equivalently,

$$a(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\left[\zeta\sin\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right)+\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\cos\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right)\right]\tag{3}$$

Note that just like your formula for $h(t)$, both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are valid for the underdamped case ($0\le\zeta<1$) as well as for the overdamped case ($\zeta > 1$), but not for the critically damped case ($\zeta=1$).

For the overdamped case, Eq. $(2)$ can be rewritten as

$$a(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n t}}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\sinh\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}+\text{arcosh}(\zeta)\right)\tag{4}$$

(by using the substitution $\zeta=\cosh(y)$).

In a similar manner, Eq. $(3)$ can be rewritten for the underdamped case as

$$a(t)=1-\frac{e^{-\zeta\omega_n t}}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\sin\left(t\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}+\arccos(\zeta)\right)\tag{5}$$

(by the substitution $\zeta=\cos(y)$), just like in your question.

Finally, in the critically damped case $\zeta=1$, the impulse response is

$$h(t)=\omega_n^2te^{-\omega_nt}\tag{6}$$

and the corresponding step response is

$$a(t)=1-e^{-\omega_nt}(\omega_nt+1)\tag{7}$$

Note that $(6)$ and $(7)$ can be obtained from the corresponding general expressions for $\zeta\neq 1$ as limits for $\zeta\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Unfortunately you have an error there! You didn't substitute the 2nd instance of t, i.e. in the argument of sinh! The actually correct result is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Et+%28exp%28-x*w*d%29*sinh%28x*w*sqrt%28d%5E2-1%29%29%29+dx). It could probably be further massaged to use an inverse hyperbolic function. That's how the arccos business comes about in the textbook derivations. But I don't really know how to that here right away.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: Oh yes, the x became a t in my Wolfram formula, so the above expression is wrong. I'll correct it as soon as I have the time to do so. What do you mean by 'do that here right away'? Reformulate Wolfram's result so that it looks like the underdamped case?

Comment: I'm not sure about equation 4 since I [can't get WA to verify for me the sinh expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinh%28t+w+sqrt%281-z%5E2%29+%2B+arrcosh%28z%29%29+), unlike the [sin expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+%28t+w+sqrt%281-z%5E2%29+%2B+arrcos%28z%29%29+). sinh(x+y) doesn't have the analogous expansion of sin(x+y) it seems.

Comment: They have same graph though http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinh%28x+sqrt+%28y%5E2+-+1%29+%2B+arccosh+y%29 vs http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+sinh%28x+sqrt%28y%5E2-1%29%29+%2B+sqrt%28y%5E2-1%29+cosh%28x+sqrt%28y%5E2-1%29%29 so I dont' know why WA doesn't manage to expand the former...

Comment: Actually sinh(x+y) [has an entirely analogous expansion with sin(x+y)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-b-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/session-20-hyperbolic-trig-functions/MIT18_01SCF10_ex20sol.pdf) just WA doesn't seem to know about it. Well, it can [verify it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinh%28x%2By%29+%3D+sinh%28x%29cosh%28y%29+%2B+cosh%28x%29sinh%28y%29).

Answer (score -1):

The inverse Laplace transformation is a complex contour integral on the s-plane with your $Y(s)$ and some exponential in the integrand. Since $Y$ is a meromorphic function that decays fast enough at infinity there must exist a closed form solution for the inverse transform in the form of linear combination of exponentials. (This might simplify to a hyperbolic or trigonometric function.) You can find the solution by picking up the contributions from the poles via the Residue Theorem. A partial fraction decomposition of $Y$ can help you treat the poles separately.