# Finding the maximum output with step function based on a transfer function

Tags: control-theory

I have an open and closed loop transfer functions as below:

$$
  \begin{align*}
    L(s) & = \dfrac{k}{s^2 + as + b} \\
    G(s) & = \dfrac{k}{s^2 + as + (b + k)}
  \end{align*}
$$

Now, I want to find the **maximum output** with a unit step as input. It might look like below:

$$
  y_{max} = \mathscr{L^{-1}}[G(s) * U(s)] = \mathscr{L^{-1}}[\dfrac{k}{s^2 + as + (b+k)} * \dfrac{1}{s}]
$$

or

$$
  y_{max} = \lim_{s\to0}sG(s)*U(s) 
$$

In most cases, we may be curious about its initial and final value to check a system. Typically, in a second-order lag system, the process before the steady-state might have oscillation based on the transfer function, and the maximum can also be higher or lower than the steady-state value.

How can I find the maximum value of the transfer function in this case? It seems not going to work with the initial and final theorem. Besides, if $a = 4, b = 2, k = 6$, what result could it be?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time and advice.

Note: I am not sure why people devote this, if there is anything not mentioned, please comment below and let me know. I mean, you can comment and devote...

Comment: There is no simple relationship between the maximum overshoot in the time domain vs frequency domain. And since this a relatively simple system, this exercise probably requires you to solve for the full time response and find its maximum.

Comment: Assuming you are learning this in a course, you have probably covered or are to find the significance of the damping ratio of a second-order system and its effects on the step response characteristics such as time-to-peak (if it peaks at all).  For some parameters $a, b$ and $k,$ the response doesn't even attain a maximum in finite-time.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza It looks like there might be a peak or not depending on the damping ratio (under-damping/over-damping). As far as I know, the peak will only show up in the under-damping case that $0 \le λ < 1$, does it mean that I have to choose some certain $a, b, k$ in order to find the maximum?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Well, I don't remember any related relation either. To me, it seems that I might need to do an inverse Laplace transform and use calculus to find the maximum...

Comment: @Sonamu That isn't that difficult of a request. I have asked my students to do this when studying this topic. There are already solutions for that on [this exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549251/inverse-laplace-transform-is-there-a-nice-formula-for-the-step-response-of-a-2n?rq=1) and the step response characteristics of a 2nd order system are all over the internet and textbooks.

Comment: Thank you, I will dig deeper into that. I have studied several textbooks and videos, and also the link you provided. I think I simply have to derive that same general formula and replace those corresponding parameters and then check which value it will result in the maximum value.

Answer (score -1):

There are three types of damping ratios in a second-order system:

1. $0 < ζ < 1$(under-damping)
2. $ζ = 1$(critical-damping)
3. $ζ > 1$(over-damping)

Each case can derive different forms of output with step function as input. Here, I will skip the whole procedure to derive three situations.

Now, with $a = 4, b = 2, k = 6$, we check the damping ratio from the general formula $ζ = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ which implies that the system oscillates and thus overshoot will happen before the steady-state.

Comment: Your calculations for the maximum are not correct. You need to compute the derivative of $y(t)$ and set it to zero. The time should also be a positive value.

Comment: Hmm. You are right, then me try it.

Comment: The derivative is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, it should be correct now. I also use online calculator for double check, lol.

Comment: Still not correct. The derivative is now fine but the rest is not. Also, $y_{max}$ is not a function of time.